# Is it possible to sort tiles in a grid-list?

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting

i got the following issue: i have a class called 'scenario' with several properties like 'id', 'name', 'number' etc.

In the html the scenarios are displayed like this:

```html
<mat-grid-list [cols]="breakpoint" rowHeight="4:4" [@gridAnimation]="(scenarios$ | async)?.length" (window:resize)="onResize($event)">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let scenario of filteredScenarios$ | async ">
      <app-scenario-card [scenario]="scenario" [routerLink]="['/scenario', scenario.id]"></app-scenario-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
```

Is it possible to sort the displayed tiles of scenarios by the chosen property (name, id, number...)? Everything i found regarding sorting is all about tables or grids.

In case its possible, could anybody show me an example how it could be done to have at least an approach?

Thank you very much.

Btw i can't just change from grid-list to table.

The class of the scenario got the following properties:

```
export class Scenario {
id: number;
scenarioName: string;
scenarioDescription: string;
periods: number; }
```

I have a search box for filtering (build analog to this tutorial --> https://blog.angulartraining.com/dynamic-filtering-with-rxjs-and-angular-forms-a-tutorial-6daa3c44076a). Now i just need a sort function for id, scenarioName and periods for example per Button or DropDown.

The code for filtering looks like this:

```
this.scenarios$ = this.scenariosService.getScenarios();
this.filter = new FormControl('');
this.filter$ = this.filter.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(''));
this.filteredScenarios$ = combineLatest(this.scenarios$, this.filter$).pipe(
  map(([Scenario, filterString]) => Scenario.filter(scenario => scenario.scenarioName.indexOf(filterString) !== -1)));
```

Comment: This might help you [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48403154/orderby-with-ngfor-array)

Answer (score 0):

You should sort `filteredScenarios$` by property before sending to template. For that I would introduce another `BehaviorSubject` that holds sorting property.

It is hard to write since you did not post your objects structure but will try.

In ts:

```
private sortProperty$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('name'); //or whatever you default sort is
filteredSortedScenarios$: Observable<Scenario>
```

and in constructor or `ngOnInt`:

```
this.filteredSortedScenarios$ = combineLatest([this.filteredScenarios$, this.sortProperty$])
  .pipe(
    map(([scenarios, sortBy]) => {
      console.log('Sorting by', sortBy);

      return scenarios.sort((a, b) => {
        switch (sortBy) {
          case 'name':
            return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);

          case 'otherProperty':
            return ...;
        }
      });
    }));
```

`combineLatest` emits whenever any of those Observables changes and in `map` you just sort the list.

When you want to change sort order, just call:

```
sortProperty$.next('nowSortByThisProperty');
```

And finally in the template you list scenarios from `filteredSortedScenarios$`:

```
<mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let scenario of filteredSortedScenarios$ | async ">
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I edited my previous post and added some information. Further i made a mistake its not javascript but typescript...sorry, my bad. Since i need to display the scenarios filtered by search and the sorted order i won't work with only ngFor="let scenario of filteredSortedScenarios$ . Sorry i'm totally new to angular and to frontend development. I appreciate any helping comment. Thanks